# How do I find a available date in mysql for date intervals?

Tags: php, mysql

**Problem**

I have a php class booking script which allows the booking of class at recurrences of every 1 - 4 week for a year.

Classes are either 30 or 60 minute durations.

If a new class is booked in a time slot it checks to see if there is a clashing class at that time of the day selected.

The script at the moment can find clashes for weekly recurrences however I haven't been able to work out how to check the recurrences of every 2 weeks+.

Some code

```
$datetime = '2015-01-13 09:00:00';
```

The SQL looks like this. (Might be suboptimal)

```
 $sql = "SELECT  datetime
        FROM    classes
        WHERE   (staff_id = :staff_id AND DAYOFWEEK(datetime) = DAYOFWEEK(:datetime))
        AND (TIME(datetime) >= TIME(:time_from) AND TIME(datetime) < TIME(:time_to))
        OR (TIME(:datetime_from) BETWEEN TIME(datetime) 
            AND TIME(ADDTIME(datetime_to, '-0 0:0:1')))";
```

If the count is > 0 then it won't allow a class to be booked at that time/day chosen for the whole year.

**Desired ability**

If there is a fortnightly class booked at say Tuesday 9am stating at 2015-01-13 09:00:00 I need to be able to use the vacancy on alternating weeks.  At the moment this blocks out every Tuesday.

I have created an array of the recurrence dates and compared that to the results from the above SQL but those results are the dates which clash.

Any ideas?